# Horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I've had my website published on weebly for over 6 months now and I just recently made some changes in the page which resulted in a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom.

I've looked on this forum and tried the different css code altering methods but I still can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas how to get rid of this horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of my website page?

I just can't figure it out..

Here's the website: http://bankboosting.com

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You have a div with an id of *483258375522454393* and a class of *wcustomhtml*, which has `overflow-y: hidden`.

Change it to `overflow:hidden`;

Comment: Any ideas where I can place this code to make it work?

Comment: What tool do you use to create the website?

Comment: Weebly website builder

Answer (score 0):

Try this(for CSS):

```
#483258375522454393{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

---

## Good Luck!

Comment: I have seen this same code mentioned on other responses here on the website in similar threads, I even tried adding it in my css, but I have no idea where to put it to make it effective.. Any ideas where I can place this code to make it work?

Comment: I don't know what that # means? I cannot search my css for that number. Weebly is very minimal in there coding options

Comment: Just add the code to your css, anywhere will do. The # Selects an element id, which, in your case, is 483258375522454393.

Comment: I added it to my css and it didn't fix the problem. I think it has to do with the very specific theme of my website.

Answer (score 0):

jstat717, you should be able to do a search in your CSS file for #483258375522454393 or overflow-y:hidden.

Once you find it, follow the directions above and change it to:

```
overflow:hidden
```